# Quel serait le terme qui conviendrait le plus dans la phrase citée dans les détails?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation

Il y a une erreur dans la nouvelle publicité de McDonald’s.

1. Les spécialistes en communication et en marketing...
2. Les experts en communication et en marketing...
3. L’équipe chargée de la communication et du marketing...
4. Les responsables de la communication et du marketing...
5. Les personnes qui ont la charge de la communication et du marketing...

...ne semblent pas très compétents en la matière.

Je trouve que « personne » est un terme trop général, trop vague dans le contexte.

Je cherche donc un terme plus spécifique qui rendrait compte de l’idée que je souhaite exprimer.
Merci.

Comment: Ce ne serait pas vraiment une erreur mais une impropriété.

Comment: @LPH C'est le postulat de la question. Le remettre en cause n'a pas de sens.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne le remets pas en cause et je ne fais que l'ajuster : il s'agit toujours d'une faute.

Comment: @LPH On n'a aucune idée de la faute dont il est question. Elle n'est pas précisée.

Comment: @jlliagre « terme trop général » : c'est la faute, non ?

Comment: @LPH Non, il y a une erreur dans une publicité mais on ne connait ni précisément de quelle publicité il s'agit, ni quelle est cette erreur.

Comment: @jlliagre Je m'en tiens à la question : je cherche un terme plus spécifique (que « personne »).

Comment: @LPH Oui, mon commentaire répondait à ton premier commentaire, pas à ta réponse.

Comment: Pour le N° 5,«  une personne en charge » n'est pas une personne sous la responsabilité directe du donneur d'ordre, c'est l'employeur intermédiaire qui est responsable  …

Comment: Chargé convient dans le monde l'Administration publique française qui donne le titre de *chargé·e·s de mission* pour des emplois qui ne relèvent pas de ses compétences directes, ou pour détacher un agent de son poste temporairement. Ce peut aussi être employé par les sous-traitants. De ce fait les *agents/employés/techniciens* se transforment en *personnes* ; ce terme convient très bien s'il s'agit de reconnaître une faute, la responsabilité de la société est discrètement atténuée, les publicitaires manipulent la langue et les esprits, c'est leur cœur de métier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Spécialistes* ou *experts*, quand on remet en doute leur compétence dans la phrase suivante, ce serait peut-être dit avec sarcasme. Par ailleurs on a aussi suggéré [responsable(s)](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/responsable/68695), *la personne qui a la charge de*, tout à fait utile : *leurs responsables de la publicité* ; on ne saurait trouver plus neutre ou générique, et significatif à la fois. Si *personne* peut sembler vague, [*gens*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gens) convient peut-être mieux en composition, *les gens du marketing de McDo*, je dirais familièrement : « les gens au marketing (de) chez McDo ». Finalement je choisirais peut-être *le marketing*, substantivé, au propre ou par ellipse des *gens* ou de *l'équipe du*... *leur marketing ne semble pas très compétent*.

Answer (score 0):

Il y a le substantif « **chargé** » qui pourrait convenir.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/charg%C3%A9/substantif)) III.− Substantif. [Correspond à charger I B 3]
> A.− Emploi subst. de l'adj. chargé, au fig.
> ♦ Rencontré en chemin de fer M. Godillot, le chargé d'illuminations, d'enthousiasme, de lampions, de clefs de villes offertes, de korolls et de danseuses bretonnes des voyages impériaux. E. et J. de Goncourt, Journal,1860, p. 735.
> ♦ Le pasteur étendit les bras et dit : − Père Miséricordieux, Christ Sauveur, ami des travaillés et des chargés, Saint Esprit inspirateur de courage et d'amour, nous te remercions d'avoir appelé cette fille de Ton Église à devenir le témoin de Ta Vérité. Chardonne, Les Destinées sentimentales,Porcelaine de Limoges, 1936, p. 230.

- les chargés de communication et de marketing

Sans quoi, « **professionnel** » est toujours à la mode, mais c'est un mot qui dans ce cas  manque en spécificité puisqu'il ne connote pas que les employés ainsi dénommés dépendent nécessairement de la firme Mac Donald's.

Answer (score 0):

Si le registre plutôt soutenu de tes suggestions n'est pas indispensable :

> Ils ont pas l'air très compétents, ceux de la com' et du marketing chez MacDo.